# MySql Indexs for where and order by clause

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems with big table indexs.

I have the table (id,external_item_id,time_stamp,status_id);

What's the best index for this 3 queries:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM items pi
 WHERE 1=1 AND external_item_id IN (1154,1155,1163,3660,6801,98)
 ORDER BY pi.time_stamp DESC, pi.id DESC
 LIMIT 12


 SELECT *
 FROM items pi
 WHERE 1=1 AND external_item_id IN (1154,1155,1163,3660,6801,98) AND status_id < 20
 ORDER BY pi.time_stamp DESC, pi.id DESC
 LIMIT 12

 SELECT *
 FROM items pi
 WHERE 1=1 AND external_item_id IN (1154,1155,1163,3660,6801,98) AND pi.time_stamp <= 13434534452 AND id < 1600
 ORDER BY pi.time_stamp DESC, pi.id DESC
 LIMIT 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the list of items for the `in`, it is hard to optimize this query.

There are basically two approaches the engine can take for these queries.  Use the index for the `where` clause.  Then either do the sort or use the index for the `oder by`.  Because there are inequalities in the `where` (`in` is an "inequality"), the index cannot be directly used for the `where`.

The best indexes for the `where` are:  `items(external_item_id, status_id)` and `items(external_item_id, time_stamp)`.

An alternative execution plan is to use the index for the `order by` and then filter on the fly.  This suggests trying:  `items(time_stamp, id, external_item_id, status_id)`.  The last two columns are so the index can satisfy the `where` without going to the original data.

None of these are perfect solutions.